# Problems with centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I define the command

```
\newcommand{\rec}[2]{\begin{center}
{\fboxsep 8pt
\fcolorbox{RoyalBlue4}{LightYellow2}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{15cm}
\textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{\large{\textsf{\bf #1}}}\\
#2
\end{minipage}}}
\end{center}}
```

But When I used it wih centerings fails, for example, if I type

```
\rec{a}{\begin{center}
b
\end{center}}
```

No problems here, but when I type

```
\rec{\begin{center}
a
\end{center}}{b}
```

Fails. Can you say me the problem?

Comment: Use `\color{RoyalBlue4}` (only one argument) instead of `\textcolor`.

Comment: I changed it but the problem persists

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with `\\`, but you really want `\par` there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\rec}[2]{\begin{center}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}%
  \fcolorbox{RoyalBlue}{LightYellow}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{15cm}
    \textcolor{RoyalBlue}{\large\sffamily\bfseries #1}\par
    #2
    \end{minipage}%
  }
  \end{center}%
}
\begin{document}
\rec{a}{\begin{center}b\end{center}}

\rec{\begin{center}a\end{center}}{b}

\end{document}
```

I changed the colors, because I don't know how yours were defined.

Notice that `\large` doesn't take an argument and that `\bf` is an obsolete command (you probably noticed that you *didn't* get sans serif type with it).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the `\color{RoyalBlue}` continues until the end.

Comment: @DiegoSilvera Sorry, I lost track of braces; fixed.

Comment: I can put `\vspace{-0.5cm}` before a `\begin{center}` to avoid the vertical space, but there is some way to avoid it. Thanks.

Comment: @DiegoSilvera Use `\centering`: `\rec{a}{\centering b}`

Answer (score 2):

In the second case the error message is "There is no line here to end", which means you are in `vertical mode`.

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\rec}[2]{\begin{center}
{\fboxsep 8pt
\fcolorbox{RoyalBlue4}{LightYellow2}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{15cm}
%\textcolor{RoyalBlue4}{\large{\textsf{\bf #1}}}%
{\color{RoyalBlue4}\large\bfseries\textsf{#1}}%
\ifhmode\expandafter\\\fi
#2
\end{minipage}}}
\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\rec{a}{\begin{center}
b
\end{center}}

\rec{\begin{center}
a
\end{center}}{b}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

after improving a bit on the OP's code:

[image: output2]

Comment: +1, but you probably want to change `\bf` into `\bfseries`: as you can see, the text is *not* in sans serif type. However, I think that `\color{...}` is preferable when the text to typeset is complex.

Comment: @egreg  agreed .